# Удаление по клику на определенный блок не работает js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема в том что удаляется только первый блок мне же нужно чтобы по нажатию к примеры на блок display2 удалялся именно он!

```js
$("div").bind("click", function(e){
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
 
document.getElementsByClassName($(this).attr("class"))[0].style.display='none';
    
});
```

```css
/* front-page.php */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* body{
 
  
} */
.main{
 width: 80%;
 position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.profile{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.profile a{
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;

  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.profiles{
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.profiles a{
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;

  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 300px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon a{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none; 
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;

} 

.hexagon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
/*   background: #fff;
   */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon,
.hexagon:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.clear{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap{
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.block {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    transform-origin: 100% 26px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    position: absolute;
}
.block:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.block:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.block:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.block:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.square {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}



.link_result{
  top: 5%;
  float: right;
}

/* end front page php  */


/* category php start */
.container-tips{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* text-align: center; */
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.container-question{
 width: 40%;
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 line-height: 3em;
 padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 100px 0 50px 1%;
}

.container-cards{
    margin:  10em 0 0 0;
    background-size:contain;
    background: url("../assets/img/arrow-line.png ") no-repeat 50%;
}
.hexagon-cards-drag {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 0 100px 0;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon-cards-drag:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    /*   background: #fff;
       */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon-cards-drag,
.hexagon-cards-drag:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}



.hexagon-cards-dragg {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0 100px 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon-cards-dragg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  /*   background: #fff;
     */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon-cards-dragg,
.hexagon-cards-dragg:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}






.container-dropped, .container-drag{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


.hexagon-cards-drop {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,200,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: dotted; /* Стиль линии внизу */
    border-bottom-color: black; /* Цвет линии внизу */
}
.hexagon-cards-drop:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    /*   background: #fff;
       */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon-cards-drop,
.hexagon-cards-drop:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}

.hexagon-cards-drag-outline {
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    border-width: 10px; /* Толщина линии внизу */
    border-style: dotted; /* Стиль линии внизу */
    border-bottom-color: black; /* Цвет линии внизу */
}


.hexagon-cards-drag-outline:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    /*   background: #fff;
       */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon-cards-drag-outline,
.hexagon-cards-drag-outline:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}

.btn{
    float: right;
}

h1{
    display: block;
}
.category_card-title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/* category php end  */


/* result php start  */
.container-result{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.hexagon-center-result{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.category-result-title{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*result php end */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-result">
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result" id="display1" >
цукуцк
                        <div class="wrap"  >dsdfsdf</div>
        
                        </div>
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result " id="display2">
                     dsfdsfdsf
                        <div class="wrap">sdfdsfsdf</div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result"  id="display3">
                      dsfdsfdsf
                        <div class="wrap">dsfdsfdsfdsffdsf></div>
                    </div>

 <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result" id="display1" >
цукуцк
                        <div class="wrap"  >dsdfsdf</div>
        
                        </div>
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result " id="display2">
                     dsfdsfdsf
                        <div class="wrap">sdfdsfsdf</div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result"  id="display3">
                      dsfdsfdsf
                        <div class="wrap">dsfdsfdsfdsffdsf></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изменил только js, т.к. вижу что Вы все равно подключаете jquery - написал на нем. Надеюсь, правильно понял что нужно сделать :)

```js
$('div.hexagon').on('click', function(){
  $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
/* front-page.php */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* body{
 
  
} */
.main{
 width: 80%;
 position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.profile{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.profile a{
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;

  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.profiles{
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.profiles a{
  top: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;

  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 300px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon a{
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none; 
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.5em;

} 

.hexagon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
/*   background: #fff;
   */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon,
.hexagon:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.clear{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap{
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.block {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    transform-origin: 100% 26px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    position: absolute;
}
.block:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.block:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.block:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.block:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.square {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}



.link_result{
  top: 5%;
  float: right;
}

/* end front page php  */


/* category php start */
.container-tips{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    /* text-align: center; */
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.container-question{
 width: 40%;
 border: 2px solid black;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 line-height: 3em;
 padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 100px 0 50px 1%;
}

.container-cards{
    margin:  10em 0 0 0;
    background-size:contain;
    background: url("../assets/img/arrow-line.png ") no-repeat 50%;
}
.hexagon-cards-drag {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 0 100px 0;
    height: 200px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon-cards-drag:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    /*   background: #fff;
       */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon-cards-drag,
.hexagon-cards-drag:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}



.hexagon-cards-dragg {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 0 100px 0;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon-cards-dragg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  /*   background: #fff;
     */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon-cards-dragg,
.hexagon-cards-dragg:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}






.container-dropped, .container-drag{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


.hexagon-cards-drop {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,200,0.5);
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: dotted; /* Стиль линии внизу */
    border-bottom-color: black; /* Цвет линии внизу */
}
.hexagon-cards-drop:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    /*   background: #fff;
       */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon-cards-drop,
.hexagon-cards-drop:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}

.hexagon-cards-drag-outline {
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    border-width: 10px; /* Толщина линии внизу */
    border-style: dotted; /* Стиль линии внизу */
    border-bottom-color: black; /* Цвет линии внизу */
}


.hexagon-cards-drag-outline:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    /*   background: #fff;
       */  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon-cards-drag-outline,
.hexagon-cards-drag-outline:before {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: .3s;
}

.btn{
    float: right;
}

h1{
    display: block;
}
.category_card-title{
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/* category php end  */


/* result php start  */
.container-result{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.hexagon-center-result{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.category-result-title{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/*result php end */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-result">
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result" id="display1" >
цукуцк
                        <div class="wrap"  >dsdfsdf</div>
        
                        </div>
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result " id="display2">
                     dsfdsfdsf
                        <div class="wrap">sdfdsfsdf</div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result"  id="display3">
                      dsfdsfdsf
                        <div class="wrap">dsfdsfdsfdsffdsf></div>
                    </div>

 <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result" id="display1" >
цукуцк
                        <div class="wrap"  >dsdfsdf</div>
        
                        </div>
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result " id="display2">
                     dsfdsfdsf
                        <div class="wrap">sdfdsfsdf</div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="hexagon hexagon-center-result"  id="display3">
                      dsfdsfdsf
                        <div class="wrap">dsfdsfdsfdsffdsf></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое все работает!Очень помог мне,спас меня,а то бы так и сидел бы без результата!

Answer (score 0):

В примере выше на jQuery елемент не удаляется из DOM, если нужно удалить вот решение на чистом js:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container-result');

const removeItem = e => {
  e.target.closest('.hexagon').remove();
};

container.addEventListener('click', removeItem);
```

Comment: ок, спасибо большое